# How to change justify depending on the size of the screen in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, justify

In my application, I use the end justified button by `justify="end"`. If there is a smaller screen (e.g. tablet) I want to change it to center justification - `justify="center"`.

My code:

```
<template>
  <v-row  justify="end" >
    <v-col cols="5">
      <v-btn
        to="/"
        >Back</v-btn
      >
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

I also tried to use css styles something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<style scoped>
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .justify{
    justify: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of the `props` you can use built in flex classes in vuetify like `.justify-md-center`

have a look at this link in the vuetify documentation:

[vuetify flex classes documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-justify)